# Can pig relational operators work on bags

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am running through the example given in [Programming Pig](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch06.html#more_on_foreach). Take a look at the --analyze_stock.pig example.

I am basically confused about how relational operators are working on bags,  I have read that **relational operators can work only on relations.**

```
daily    = load 'NYSE_daily' as (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray,
               date:chararray, open:float, high:float, low:float,
               close:float, volume:int, adj_close:float);
grpd     = group daily by symbol;
```

After running these two statements if i run

```
describe grpd
```

The output i get is

```
{group: chararray,daily: {(exchange: chararray,symbol: chararray,date: chararray,open: float,high: float,low: float,close: float,volume: int,adj_close: float)}}
```

This clearly shows that daily is a bag

The next statement in the script is

```
analyzed = foreach grpd {
            sorted = order daily by date;
            generate group, analyze(sorted);
```

Here the order (relational operator) is being applied on daily (bag) based on the describe statement above.

I realize that in all probability that my concepts are a little weak here, would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that a bag is an unordered collection of tuples. Also remember that the records in a Pig relation are tuples. That means that a relation is actually just a big bag. That means that conceptually, anything you can do to a whole relation you can also do to a smaller bag in a single record. This is done using a [nested foreach](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch06.html#x028).

In practice, they are not identical -- when dealing with a bag, there are not map-reduce cycles involved; it's more like using a UDF. Consequently, not every operator can be used this way. Note that the source I linked to is out-of-date on this point: you can now use, e.g., `GROUP BY` as well.

Comment: Can we say that the relational operators allowed inside nested foreach are applicable to bags also ?

Comment: What do you mean? When using the operators inside a nested foreach, you are by definition applying them to bags.

Comment: Ya we are, but the documentation stated that the relational operators can be applied only to relations, hence I was just clarifying that it can be applied to bags as well

Comment: Perhaps it would benefit the question if you quoted from the documentation you are thinking of, and I can address the quote specifically.

Comment: This post [here](http://www.edureka.in/blog/operators-in-apache-pig/) "A Pig Latin statement is an operator that takes a relation as input and produces another relation as output." This lead me to question how operators are being applied to bags. Even [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-apachepigdataquery/) says "All Pig Latin statements operate on relations (and are called relational operators)" But they also mention "A bag is a relation, similar to table" so i guess that along with your answer clears it up for me :) Thanks

Comment: Just to conclude bags are relations and hence pig latin operators can be applied to bags as well, In hind sight this was pretty obvious !!